# Can you plot an irrational transfer function on matlab?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, bode

For example if I have the following transfer function:

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{s/10})}$$

Can I do the bode plot it in matlab or do I need to rationalize it beforehand?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I was looking into irrational transfer functions , and I could not find any refrence. I have not tried anything since I have no idea where to start

Comment: The Bode plot is the magnitude and phase of H(s) as you limit s to be the $j\omega$ axis. So as long as you can compute a magnitude and phase of the function, you can plot it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a problem for you, I recommend taking a basic Matlab class first.

```
%% plot a transfer function
% frequency axis
omega = logspace(-2,2,1000)';
% calculate the trasnfer function
H = 1./cosh(sqrt(1i*omega/10));

% and plot it
clf;
subplot(2,1,1);
semilogx(omega,10*log10(H.*conj(H)));
grid on;
ylabel('Level in dB');
xlabel('Frequency in Rad/sec');
subplot(2,1,2);
semilogx(omega,unwrap(angle(H)));
grid on;
ylabel('Phase in rad');
xlabel('Frequency in Rad/sec');
```

Comment: Expressing frequencies in Hz and angles in degrees is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @TimWescott or incurs an additional charge of $3.99 plus tax and tip. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's `bode` function is just a wrapper for calculating a system response and then graphing it.

So, just do that by hand.